# Samsung Galaxy Core Plus

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I want to know if I could install ubuntu touch on a Samsung Galaxy Core Plus.  I have not tried anything yet, I am looking into buying this phone but I would like to know if I can get ubuntu on it first.

Comment: Hardware related question and hardware recommedations are off topic on askubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

That might work, but it will not be easy, since it is not in the [list of currently ported devices](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices), so [you probably have to write a lot of code to port it](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/porting-new-device/) (drivers, firmwares and such).

In the linked pages there are all the instructions and links that you need to do it, but be sure to understand that it is not an easy task.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Might as well look for something easy and buy something from the list.

Comment: If you want a phone with Ubuntu the best thing is to buy a phone with Ubuntu preinstalled (I own a bq Aquaris e4.5 and it's great!) or, if you really want to start with Android at first, I suggest that you have a good look at Nexus 5, for which there is already a lot of work done.

Comment: I am not sure about the ubuntu phone. I want something fast with at least 16gb internal storage with external SD storage up to 128gb